# Why does adding files to my args also open the buffers?

Tags: vim, buffer

Whenever I add files to my `args`, the same files are also added to my list of buffers. This happens with `set hidden` and `set nohidden`. This is not the expected behaviour, right? And how do I stop it?

```
:ls
  1  a   "[No Name]"                    line 1
:args *
:ls
  1  a   "[No Name]"                    line 1
  3 %a   "globals.js"                   line 1
  4      "package.json"                 line 0
  5      "README.md"                    line 0
  6      "spec"                         line 0
  7      "tags"                         line 0
```

`Spec` is a directory not a file, which prompted me to experiment with disabling `NERDTree` but that made no difference.

Comment: This is completely expected. Every "argument" ends up in the buffer list.

Answer (score 0):

It is the standard/normal behavior.

You can switch to the next file using `:next`.